# localStorage not storing prepended comments

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/kBD3X/9/) is the fiddle. I am trying to store prepended comments in a `ul` by saving the `ul` as a `var`, and use `localStorage` on it to save it to the browser.

HTML:

```
<h1>Commentia!!!</h1>
<textarea id='type'></textarea>
<br />
<input type='text' id='input'>
<br />
<br />
<button id='b' onclick='comment()'>Submit</button>
<div id='box'>Type your comment
<br />(please use spaces)</div>
<div id='button'>Click to submit</div>
<div id='inp'>Type your name</div>
<div id='dialog'></div>
<h3>Comments</h3>
<ul id='ul'></ul>
```

JS:

```
var l = $('#ul').val();
localStorage.comments = l;
document.getElementById('ul').innerHTML = localStorage.comments;
```

Comment: You should conmsider using the `setItem` & `getItem` methods of the `localStorage` object as described by the standards (http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-webstorage-20130730/) instead of using the shortcut properties that are supported by some, but not all browsers. That will give you fewer headaches in the long run

Comment: @MartinJespersen Do you know if Chrome supports the shortcut property?

Answer (score 0):

`val()` is apparently meant for getting the [values of form elements](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Trying it on a list returns an empty string. You could just get the innerhtml using `$('#ul').html()`, then stringifying that for `localStorage`.

Something like:

```
var l = $('#ul').html();
localStorage.comments = JSON.stringify(l);
```

To restore these at some later point (I use jQuery here since that's available anyway):

```
$('#ul').html(JSON.parse(localStorage.comments));
```

(Untested). Any particular reason for taking this approach?

Edit: it's easy enough to check what is actually being saved. In Chrome, the devtools are in the Chrome menu under `Tools`, or right-click anywhere in a webpage and `Inspect element`.

LocalStorage (and a bunch of other stuff) is listed in the `Resources` tab. You can also go to the `Console` tab and type `localStorage` to access the object directly.

Keep in mind localStorage only stores strings and is limited to 5MB per 'origin', which I take to mean host. If you do lots of testing on localhost, I imagine there's a chance you'll hit the quota at some point.

Also, the previous commenter has a good point about using `getItem()`/`setItem()`. Instead of using `localStorage.comments` you'd use `localStorage.getItem('comments')`.

Comment: it still doesn't seem to save. Does [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) support this?

Comment: You can really easily test localStorage by using the console. Open your preferred devtools and type `localStorage`. If you do that on this page, you'll probably see some settings SO is saving (like your OpenID provider). I also haven't actually tested the code above. Another reason it might fail is if you're trying this locally, make sure your localStorage hasn't exceeded its quota (clear it out for `localhost`).

Comment: I have no idea how to open dev tools.

Comment: So the whole script for the `localStorage` would be:
`var l = $('#ul').html();
    localStorage.setItem('comments', l);          document.getElementById('ul').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('comments');`